# Drupal 8 + AWS ElastiCache Redis : Connection timed out

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, redis, drupal-8

I have setup AWS ElastiCache Redis in Cluster mode via

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/setting-up-a-redis-cluster-with-amazon-elasticache/

On Drupal 8 I installed https://www.drupal.org/project/redis

In **settings.php** I have below code.

```
// To check redis is installed or not.

if (phpversion('redis')) {
  // Redis Settings
  $settings['redis.connection']['interface'] = 'PhpRedis';
  $settings['redis.connection']['host']      = 'xxxxx.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com';  // Your Redis instance hostname (Configuration endpoint).
  $settings['redis.connection']['port']      = '6379';

  // Use for all bins otherwise specified.
  $settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis';
  $settings['cache_prefix'] = 'prod_';
  $settings['container_yamls'][] = $app_root . '/modules/contrib/redis/example.services.yml';
  $settings['container_yamls'][] = $app_root . '/modules/contrib/redis/redis.services.yml';
}
```

It is giving below error

> RedisException: Connection timed out in
>   /web/modules/contrib/redis/src/Client/PhpRedis.php:28

Seems issue with hostname, but it is correct which I put from AWS. Not sure what else can be issue?

Comment: start with testing the connection from the web server, e.g. `nc -v xxxxx.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com 6379`

Comment: I think it may caused by the Transit encryption mode, you can try to should use tls.